# How can I display the ending path of a url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can display a path like this:

```
<%= request.request_uri %> or <%= request.path %>
```

And I will get something like this:

```
/controller/action/foo1/foo2
```

How can I just get the ending path without a slash? Like in this example, it would be: "foo2". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.path.split('/').last
```

I'm not why you should ever use this though. Using `params` is the sensible approach, as @Sam said.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the last part of the url is your `:id`.